# What if a new romantic interest wants you to carry stuff through customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Say there's a relatively new romantic interest (e.g. a month old, dating exclusively). But all of a sudden they want to bring over a dozen large boxes of candy from a foreign country as gifts for their friends. They want you to help by taking half of those boxes through customs.

How best to handle this situation?

Comment: As long it's just candy and you're not exceeding your personal limit, this is fairly common between friends, family and partners. Grab a bottle of wine too ;)

Comment: And if it's *not* just candy, but something more sinister, then you're probably in for a pretty unpleasant experience no matter whether you knew about it or not. You might avoid the jail sentence at the end if you can somehow prove you didn't know about it.

Comment: Nope.  Just nope.  Don't ever carry anything for anyone.

Comment: Six large boxes of candy could easily be more than 23kg. What's the weight of this?

Comment: @MastaBaba I don't know the weight

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to really answer. If I'm visiting a friend overseas and he asks me to bring some gifts, I have no problem buying them from local stores and bringing them with me. I would know what is in those packages as much as anything I buy from any store. If someone I've known for just a month is handing me strange packages from who knows where and is asking me to carry them across borders, then I'm not doing that. So which is it here?

Comment: As worded, this is asking for relationship advice, not travel advice. I'm not sure if there is a stack for that.

Comment: I'd echo that.  If the friend says: "Please buy some X candy and give it to Y" then, subject to practical issues, I would.  However, if they said: "Please take this box for me" then I would not.  I would need to know someone way longer than a month to trust with something like that.  It could be embarrassing to decline but it could be much worse to accept.

Comment: Just find an excuse and don't go. If she insists then there's definitely something fishy there. Find an excuse that you have to do something on that day so that she won't know that you're doing it because you don't trust her.

Comment: Someone asked her if she could carry 18 headphones. Sure, no biggie. http://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/incidents/photo-of-alleged-drug-haul-emerges-as-fears-are-raised-over-cassandra-sainsburys-safety-in-colombia/news-story/f6063d24dd95e86f67ea19584dc91876

Comment: Don't take anything for anyone else through customs, unless you know exactly what it is.  If you buy the candy yourself from a store you trust, and know it's candy and not something nefarious, it's fine, but your situation sounds suspicious.  It's not uncommon for people to get others to be their mules for importing illegal commodities.

Comment: Nope. Although it was a mailed package rather than personally carried, I saw a package from Asia of supposed "candy". Looked great, sealed wrappers...actually contained an illegal substance like meth or an ingredient to make meth. Seen on Canada's Border Force show.

Comment: @Moo: Really, not *ever* for *anyone*?  You wouldn’t carry something for your parents, or for your spouse of ten years?

Comment: @PLL yup, not even in those circumstances

Comment: @choster:  Maybe the [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) stack?

Answer (score 15):

> How best to handle this situation?

Are you not comfortable with the personal side or the customs side of this situation? If it's the personal relationship side, and you're not comfortable, then don't do it.

If it's the customs side of it, I'd say go for it. If it is **you** buying the candy, from a **regular** store, where **you** picked it from the shelf, and **paid for it with your money**, then I don't see any downside to that. People bring gifts for others all the time. As long as you don't exceed the limits for bringing gifts into the country, then you should be fine.

A huge red flag would be if this new romantic interest told you to go to some shady store, and ask a stranger for 12 boxes of chocolate, and you don't know what is in it, then I wouldn't do it.

Comment: I once carried an audio tape recording for a complete stranger. Nothing happened. Nobody picked it up after I crossed. It made me feel uneasy the entire flight. I don't carry stuff for strangers anymore.

Comment: What was on the tape?

Comment: What difference does it make whose money?  The important thing is you buy it from a store you pick.

Comment: @LorenPechtel That is true. I guess I was making the assumption OP was going to be given a credit card or something traceable.

Comment: BTW, also ensure that the candy is under **your** control after purchase--no way they can swap boxes.